# getContentResolver() method in Image View Application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I just came across the following code while implementing an Image gallery in Android.

```
Intent data = getIntent();
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(data.getData());
```

The getContentResolver returns the ContentResolver Object.But I am confused as to how does it fit in this code? What exactly does this piece of code is doing.Forgive my naiveness as I am a beginner in android.

Comment: Learn ContentProvider in android . and please learn FileProvider for more info.

Comment: "What exactly does this piece of code is doing" -- it is crashing with a `NullPointerException`, most likely. I feel rather confident that those two lines did not appear in succession as you show them here. Given a valid `Uri` pointing to a stream, `openInputStream()` opens the stream. However, `new Intent()` does not contain a valid `Uri`.

Answer (score 1):

`getIntent()`, called on an `Activity`, returns the `Intent` that was used to originally create this activity.

`getData()`, called on an `Intent`, returns the `Uri` inside of that `Intent`, if any.

`openInputStream()`, called on a `ContentResolver` and passed a `Uri`, opens an `InputStream` on the stream identified by that `Uri`, so the bytes represented by that stream can be read in. For example, if the `Uri` points to an image, `BitmapFactory` has a `decodeStream()` method that can read in the bytes for that image and give you a `Bitmap` back representing the image.